# flutter: how to get the index of the selected item in ListWheelChildLoopingListDelegate?

Tags: flutter

I have put a list of numbers(1-23) and a `'-'` in a `ListWheelScrollView()` to display `time-selecting` feature,(just in the following picture). I want add some feature in the item that is selected currently such as bold font, so my problem is `how to get the selected item index`? My code is below.

```
new ListWheelScrollView.useDelegate(
                            itemExtent: 48,
                            physics: FixedExtentScrollPhysics(),
                            childDelegate: ListWheelChildLoopingListDelegate(
                              children: List<Widget>.generate(24, (index) {
                                if (index < 0 || index > 24) return null;
                                else if (index == 0) return Container(
                                  child: Text('-', style: CalendarTextStyle.timeStyle),
                                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                                );
                                else return Container(
                                  child: Text('${index}', style: CalendarTextStyle.timeStyle),
                                  alignment: Alignment.center,);
                              })
                            ),
                          ),
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ListWheelScrollView/onSelectedItemChanged.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution. use `onSelectedItemChanged` property in `ListWheelScrollView.useDelegate`, which can listen the item index when scolling.

```
ListWheelScrollView.useDelegate(
                        onSelectedItemChanged: (index) {setState(() {seletedItem = index;});}, // I initialized selectedItem = 0 in `initState()`
                        itemExtent: 48,
                        squeeze: 1,
                        controller: fsc,
                        physics: FixedExtentScrollPhysics(),
                        childDelegate: ListWheelChildLoopingListDelegate(
                          children: List<Widget>.generate(24, (index) {
                            if (index < 0 || index > 24) return null;
                            else if (index == 0) {
                              return Container(
                                child: Text('-', style:
                              seletedItem == index ?
                              CalendarTextStyle.selectedTimeStyle : CalendarTextStyle.timeStyle),
                              alignment: Alignment.center,);}
                            else {
                              return Container(
                                child: Text('$index', style:
                                seletedItem == index ?
                                CalendarTextStyle.selectedTimeStyle : CalendarTextStyle.timeStyle),
                                alignment: Alignment.center,);}
                          })
                        ),
                      ),
```

then we can got the effort like this: we can change the style of the selected item.

[image]

[image]